# How to iterate through intervals in R and change variables in For loop?

Tags: r, for-loop

So this is a for loop that I am trying to use to iterate like this:

```
n <- 2
b <- 1
for(i in seq(from=1, to=5, by=n)){
  test_buffer <- st_buffer(manhattan_data$geometry[i:n*b], dist=300)
  nam <- paste("buffer", i, sep="_")
  assign(nam, test_buffer)
  b <- b + 1
}
```

I want this loop to give me the result of this output, but for some reason only the first iteration works fine and I can't figure out why:

```
st_buffer(manhattan_data$geometry[1:2], dist=300) 
st_buffer(manhattan_data$geometry[3:4], dist=300) 
st_buffer(manhattan_data$geometry[5:6], dist=300)
```

Comment: I don't have data to check the output but does it work if you add `()` for `n*b` ? This maybe because of operator precedence. Try `manhattan_data$geometry[i:(n*b)]`

Comment: Saying I'm trying to do "X" with "this code" and not really describing what X might be in clear natural language is bound to cause frustration. Please try to write  an unambiguous problem description. And DO present a [MCVE]

Answer (score 0):

```
n <- 2
i = seq(from=1, to=5, by=n)
result = lapply(i, function(i) {
  st_buffer(manhattan_data$geometry[i:(i+1)], dist=300)
})
names(result) <- paste0('buffer_',i)
```